# Garbage Collector runs every second start of my app

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I have a strange behaviour. My App starts very fast when first started. 
When starting the second time (closed the app before and checked with taskmanager that it is no longer running ) it runs very slow. 3rd time fast, 4th time slow. every second start runs slow. Its because my Garbage Collector starts working the second time, but I don't know why. Should a start of an App behaves always the same ?

My Step which is very slow is my decodeStream - Statement. I have about 100 small pictures (5 kbytes - 15kbytes) I want to load.

```
Log.v("DEBUG DRAWEVENT 71","load " + e.sEventTitle);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(fImage), null, o2);
Log.v("DEBUG DRAWEVENT 72","end load " + e.sEventTitle);
```

LogCat that shows Garbage-Collection activities ( Only every 2. start )

```
01-04 16:16:03.500: V/DEBUG DRAWEVENT 71(20427): load Title
01-04 16:16:03.641: D/dalvikvm(20427): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 33% free 28448K/41924K, paused 138ms, total 138ms
01-04 16:16:03.641: I/dalvikvm-heap(20427): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.842MB for 34612-byte allocation
01-04 16:16:03.771: D/dalvikvm(20427): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 33% free 28481K/41960K, paused 138ms, total 138ms
01-04 16:16:03.781: V/DEBUG DRAWEVENT 72(20427): end load Title
```

I am on API Level 12.

Any hints ?

New analysing facts : After first start the App runns still under cached processes (35MB). Cached Processes can be shown under settings->apps->Running->Show Cached Processes.
When stopping this process my second start runns fast too.

So the next question. How to prevent an app to be cached ?

Comment: It may be because, On the first run it will use the free cache and on the second run there may be less memory available so GC comes in to play and clear cache

Comment: Right away I can see you are not closing the `FileInputStream` and you likely have other leaks. Post more code and we can check it.

Comment: If my app would leak, shouldn't the leaks be gone when terminating the app. I mean the first, 3rd and 5th start are running without GC. 2nd 4th and so one have GC-Activities. I recognized, that after the first start the app is cached with 32MB. Why ? I guess, that is the problem.

Comment: How can I prevent an app to be cached. Or how can I teminate an app, so that it will not be cached ? ( Kill process ? )